# ColdFusion 2018 Standard 2 node cluster with J2EE shared sessions for failover

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, coldfusion, cluster-computing, failover

Why we want to configure that setup?

We would like to have a Blue/Green zero downtime setup for our CF2018 App.

We currently have a basic CF Server Install (IIS + CF2018) in one server that connects to another Server for the DB (we are using CF2018 Standard).

Our app uses J2EE sessions

There are posts that explain how to use the External Session Storage feature included in CF (redis) but that won’t work with J2EE sessions, the CF admin interface wont allow it.

How can I setup 2 servers in a cluster (behind a load balancer) with J2EE session failover functionality by using CF2018 Standard Edition?